# How to fetch a value from db using multiple and in queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch a data belonging to user id.
now i want to fetch the data based on 2 conditions.i want the records of idle and active users to be displayed.

i have used the below query to do so.but i am not able to retrieve the data.

here the product_proposer is user_id.one user_id has many products.i want to fetch the data belonging to that user id where the product_status is $active and $soldout.

The below query returns `output-1`

```
SELECT product_id,product_name FROM product_list WHERE product_proposed_user_id ='12' AND product_publish_status = '0'
```

output-1:

```
94 MARSHALL MG SERIES MG15CFX GUITAR COMBO AMP CARBON...
95 SESSION STUDIO CLASSIC
```

******---

query-2:

```
SELECT product_id,product_name FROM product_list WHERE product_proposed_user_id ='12' AND product_publish_status = '4'
```

returns 
output-2:

```
213 Mountain bike
```

now i want the output by combining both the queries i.e

```
SELECT product_id,product_name FROM product_list WHERE product_proposed_user_id ='12' AND product_publish_status = '0' AND product_publish_status = '4'
```

so that output should be:

```
94 MARSHALL MG SERIES MG15CFX GUITAR COMBO AMP CARBON...
95 SESSION STUDIO CLASSIC
213 Mountain bike
```

but when i run this query its returning nothing.

How can i solve this?

Comment: How can `user_status` be both `idle` and `$active` in the same row?

Comment: You can't have two `FROM` clauses in the same query. Did you mean to write a `JOIN`?

Comment: If you want both idle and active users, you should use `AND user_status IN ('idle', 'active')`

Comment: Did you really mean to have `$` before `active`?

Comment: Please show some sample input data, and the result you're trying to get from it.

Comment: please show your table structure and be specific about your requirements..

Comment: @Dasrath i have edited the post to understand in more simpler way.

Comment: if you want data from two tables than you have to use JOIN instead of two FROM.

Comment: @Barmar i have edited the post to understand in more simpler way.

Comment: you are using $ .. are you using php??

Comment: `WHERE x AND y AND z` means that all 3 conditions have to be true on the **same** row for that row to be included in the result. `product_status` can't have two different values in a single row, so nothing will ever match your condition.

Comment: How does `$active` and `$soldout` relate to finding idle and active users?

Comment: I'll ask you again: Please post some sample data and the result you're trying to get.

Comment: @Mithun first check what Barmar is trying to explain??

Comment: @MithunRaikar Try with `mysql regular expression`

Comment: @barmer edited the post with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to highlight the basic rule of AND and OR operator in SQL

```
SELECT product_id,product_name FROM product_list 
WHERE product_proposed_user_id ='12' 
      AND product_publish_status = '0' 
      AND product_publish_status = '4'
```

Above is your query

You mentioned SQL server to get you the results `from product_list where 
product_proposed_user_id ='12' 
AND product_publish_status = '0' 
AND product_publish_status = '4'`

Now SQL will search the records in `product_list where
product_proposed_user_id ='12' 
AND product_publish_status = '0' 
AND product_publish_status = '4'`

However, there will no single record in product_list having product_publish_status equal to '0' and '4'. Therefore it is returning you 0 records

In order to get the desired output you will need to write the query as

```
SELECT product_id,product_name FROM product_list 
WHERE 
(product_proposed_user_id ='12' AND product_publish_status = '0') 
  OR 
(product_proposed_user_id ='12' AND product_publish_status = '4')
```

And you will get the output as expected. Please try and let us know.

Refer: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp